# How to balance bibliography and insert a full width tabular block after

Tags: bibliographies, fullwidth

I am having some trouble with the last page of my manuscript, where I want to have the full 2 column bibliography , followed by a `tabular*` block.

This is dummy version of what my code looks like:

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage[caption=false,font=footnotesize]{subfig}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{balance}
\usepackage{dblfloatfix}

\begin{document}

\title{\LARGE \bf Example Title
}

\author{Author 1, Author 2
}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
Dummy abstract here.Dummy abstract here.Dummy abstract here. Dummy abstract here. Dummy abstract here. Dummy abstract here. Dummy abstract here.
\end{abstract}

\begin{IEEEkeywords}
Keyword1, Keyword 2
\end{IEEEkeywords}


\section{Introduction}

A proposal by a British government agency to let the Internet suggest a name for a 287 million polar research ship probably seemed like a good idea at the time. Now, the agency is the latest group to see what happens when web users are asked to unleash their creative energy: R.R.S. Boaty McBoatface~\cite{REF1} is a clear front-runner. People quickly disregarded the more dignified names suggested by the Natural Environment Research Council — Shackleton, Endeavour, Falcon.~\cite{REF2,REF3,REF4} Instead the contest became the latest in the Internet’s long, storied history to end up with social media users gleefully offering ridiculous names to government-funded projects. The initiatives are often hilarious but don’t often succeed.~\cite{REF5,REF6,REF7} Remember when Slovak lawmakers overrode the public’s vote in 2012 to rename a pedestrian bridge after the actor Chuck Norris? Or the debacle in Austin, Tex., a year earlier, when people unsuccessfully tried to name the city’s waste management service after Limp Bizkit’s frontman, Fred Durst Corporations have also tried the tactic, and the penalty for trying to play with the Internet tends to be meaner: Mountain Dew ~\cite{REF8,REF9,REF10}learned the hard way when 4 Chan took control of a vote to name a new flavor, and the joke was on Taylor Swift and VH1 when the Internet chose a school for the deaf as a concert location.

\balance
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{my_bibliography}


\begin{table*}[b]
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{p{1.8cm}b{3.2cm}p{1.8cm}b{3.2cm}p{1.8cm}b{3.2cm}}
Photo author1  &  Bio author1  & Photo author2  &  Bio author2 & Photo author3  &  Bio author3 \\[1.5mm]
Photo author4  &  Bio author4  & Photo author5  &  Bio author5 & Photo author6  &  Bio author6 \\[1.5mm]
Photo author7  &  Bio author7  & Photo author8  &  Bio author8 & Photo author9 &  Bio author9  
\end{tabular*}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

I've tried using the `balance` package, putting a `\balance` just before the bibliography and a `\nobalance` after it, but it didn't work (somehow putting the \nobalance command also seems to break things)

I basically just want the bibliography to be balanced, and then at the very end insert my full width table.

I read putting my tabular block withing a table* block would work if I also used the package dblfloatfix to locate that table at the bottom of the page. But the table always ends up in a different page....

The my_bibliography bib file just contains the following entry over and over again (REF1 through REF10):

```
@Article{REF1,
  author="Boaty McBoat Face, Harambe J.K",
  title="Design and characterization of sciency stuff. Also need the title of this to be longer so I can fill the page quicker with references",
  journal="Science and stuff",
  volume="13",
  number="10",
  year="2013"
}

@Article{REF2,
  author="Boaty McBoat Face, Harambe J.K",
  title="Design and characterization of sciency stuff. Also need the title of this to be longer so I can fill the page quicker with references",
  journal="Science and stuff",
  volume="13",
  number="10",
  year="2013"
}

@Article{REF3,
  author="Boaty McBoat Face, Harambe J.K",
  title="Design and characterization of sciency stuff. Also need the title of this to be longer so I can fill the page quicker with references",
  journal="Science and stuff",
  volume="13",
  number="10",
  year="2013"
}

@Article{REF4,
  author="Boaty McBoat Face, Harambe J.K",
  title="Design and characterization of sciency stuff. Also need the title of this to be longer so I can fill the page quicker with references",
  journal="Science and stuff",
  volume="13",
  number="10",
  year="2013"
}

@Article{REF5,
  author="Boaty McBoat Face, Harambe J.K",
  title="Design and characterization of sciency stuff. Also need the title of this to be longer so I can fill the page quicker with references",
  journal="Science and stuff",
  volume="13",
  number="10",
  year="2013"
}

@Article{REF6,
  author="Boaty McBoat Face, Harambe J.K",
  title="Design and characterization of sciency stuff. Also need the title of this to be longer so I can fill the page quicker with references",
  journal="Science and stuff",
  volume="13",
  number="10",
  year="2013"
}

@Article{REF7,
  author="Boaty McBoat Face, Harambe J.K",
  title="Design and characterization of sciency stuff. Also need the title of this to be longer so I can fill the page quicker with references",
  journal="Science and stuff",
  volume="13",
  number="10",
  year="2013"
}

@Article{REF8,
  author="Boaty McBoat Face, Harambe J.K",
  title="Design and characterization of sciency stuff. Also need the title of this to be longer so I can fill the page quicker with references",
  journal="Science and stuff",
  volume="13",
  number="10",
  year="2013"
}

@Article{REF9,
  author="Boaty McBoat Face, Harambe J.K",
  title="Design and characterization of sciency stuff. Also need the title of this to be longer so I can fill the page quicker with references",
  journal="Science and stuff",
  volume="13",
  number="10",
  year="2013"
}

@Article{REF10,
  author="Boaty McBoat Face, Harambe J.K",
  title="Design and characterization of sciency stuff. Also need the title of this to be longer so I can fill the page quicker with references",
  journal="Science and stuff",
  volume="13",
  number="10",
  year="2013"
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Perhaps with `biblatex-ieee`?